# Edit blackhole message on CakePHP

Tags: security, cakephp, csrf

On CakePHP, with component Security turned on, and CSRF too, when the component catches something it considers as attack, it throws an error message.

> The request has been black-holed
>
> Error: The requested address '/login' was not found on this server.

Even with `debug` set to `0`, the error message shows up. Which means nothing to average user and can confuse anyone because, after all, the requested address exists.

Is there any way to edit that message without touching CakePHP core code? Or maybe redirect to referrer with `$this->data` empty?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can edit the `error400.ctp` and `error500.ctp` in your `app/View/Errors/` folder and override the messages.

Comment: Gotcha. Thanks. I thought this error message had to be handled in a different way.

Comment: For more advanced rendering customization you can use your custom exception renderer which extends core's `ExceptionRenderer` class. But to achieve what you mentioned that's not needed.